# Can I use a json ld schema as a sitemap for react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, seo, json-ld, react-helmet

In react I can use helmet to create a json ld schema with links, is this actually good for seo purposes. Is there a different way to use json ld for this in back end with mongo db and express. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! If you're using MongoDB and Express on the backend, you can create an Express route to dynamically generate JSON-LD data based on your MongoDB content. This data can be fetched on the React frontend and injected into the HTML head for SEO purposes. Helmet can still be used in React for managing the head, but the JSON-LD itself is generated dynamically on the backend.